# How to show that the cross-ratio is invariant under Moebius transformations without using generator matrices of $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{C})$

Tags: geometry, invariance

I am given the following problem set:

> Show that the cross-ratio is invariant under Moebius transformation, meaning that $$D \left(L_g(z_1),L_g(z_1),L_g(z_1),L_g(z_1)\right) = D(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4) \qquad \forall z_i \in  \mathbb{P}_1\mathbb{C} \quad i= 1, \ldots,4 \qquad \quad \text{where}\quad  z_1 \neq z_4 \ , \ z_2 \neq z_3 \quad \text{and} \quad \forall g \in \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$$
>   without using the generating matrices of GL$(2,\mathbb{C})$

**The way they don't want to see:**

Since we know that GL$(2,\mathbb{C})$ is generated by the matrices: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ we can show that the cross-ratio is invariant under each of these matrices. Henceforth this way is not the one they are looking for so I am puzzled how to prove it.

Maybe by showing that $L_g$ is bijective ?

Comment: I suspect that you're supposed to say "Let $L$ be the trasnform with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Then $w_i = L(z_i)$ is $\frac{aw_i + b} {cw_i + d}$, so $D(w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4) = \ldots$" and write out that expression, and then simplify like mad, allowing yourself to divide by $ad-bc$ as needed during the simplification, because you know that's nonzero. In other words: algebra hell. Perhaps the point is to teach you that proving things on a generating set is a good idea. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes I was thinking of that idea (proving things on a generating set) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S(z)= (z, z_2, z_3, z_4)$ and $T(z)$ be a Mobius Transformation, then $ST^{-1}(z)$
takes $T(z_2)$ to $1$, $T(z_3)$ to $0$, and $T(z_4)$ to $\infty$. In other words, $ST^{-1}(z)=(z, T(z_2),T(z_3),T(z_4))$. Therefore $(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=S(z_1)=ST^{-1}(T(z_1))=(T(z_1),T(z_2),T(z_3),T(z_4))$.

Comment: This is a really terrific proof. Note to Mainviel: Tim is using $(a, b, c, d)$ to denote what you call $D(a, b, c, d)$, and when he writes $ST^{-1}(z)$, he means the function $z \mapsto S(T^{-1}(z))$, which took me a little while to realize.

Comment: @ John Hughes I can't take credit. The proof is from Ahlfors.